# Create database user with DDL in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, ddl

I am trying to create a user using DDL in DB2. I tried this:

```
CREATE USER 'test_user' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

and I got this error message:

```
An unexpected token "'test_user' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'password'" was found following "CREATE USER ".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.24.92
```

when I remove the apostrophes:

```
CREATE USER test_user IDENTIFIED BY password
```

I get this:

```
An unexpected token "USER" was found following "CREATE ".  Expected tokens may include:  "VARIABLE".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.24.92
```

I have full admin rights and I am running DB2 Warehouse on Cloud Type:Enterprise Plan - Single Node

Comment: There is no such Db2-LUW statement as `create user`. There is a `create schema` statement..  So , edit your question to explain what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: @mao thank you mao. What I am REALLY trying to do is find a way to quickly and easily create users in DB2. we have about 900 users to start with and we need to create about 15 every week.

Comment: See my answer below. Db2WhoC has an API that can be utilized by admins to manage users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take a look at [SQL statements supported by Db2 Warehouse on Cloud](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011049.html), you will notice that there is no `CREATE USER` statement. Hence the error message.

Check out the [section on user management](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.security.doc/doc/user_mgmnt.html) or see the [API to create a new user](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/db2-warehouse-on-cloud#creates-a-new-user-admin-only).